# What kind of chilli plant is this?

Tags: identification, chili

I grew this chili plant from some seeds I had from some left over dried chillies a couple of years ago. It is now around 4 months old and has these nice chilli peppers. By the looks of it, it seems like jalapeño but I would like to confirm what species it is. There is a bit of variation between the first one it grew that came out very straight and the other two which came out crooked.

Any idea what type of chilli it is?

[image: chilli plant]

Answer (score 1):

There are five domesticated species of chili peppers.

- [Capsicum annuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_annuum) includes many common varieties such as bell peppers, wax, cayenne, jalapeños, Thai peppers, chiltepin, and all forms of New Mexico chile.
- [Capsicum frutescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_frutescens) includes malagueta, tabasco, piri piri, and Malawian Kambuzi.
- [Capsicum chinense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_chinense) includes the hottest peppers such as the naga, habanero, Datil and Scotch bonnet.
- [Capsicum pubescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_pubescens) includes the South American rocoto peppers.
- [Capsicum baccatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_baccatum) includes the South American aji peppers.

Given the growth habit of your plant, the ***Species*** is most certainly *Capsicum annuum*. But that isn't really what you were after, you want to know the ***Cultivar***.

Unfortunately, no one is going to be able to tell you 100% for sure what cultivar it is. There are just too many very similar cultivars out there. I will say that too me it doesn't look anything like a jalapeno, more like a *de árbol* or *aji*. You don't remember what sort of chili you took the seeds from or even where you bought it?

Have a look [here](https://www.chilipeppermadness.com/chili-pepper-types/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Capsicum_cultivars#Capsicum_annuum) for some incomplete lists of cultivars.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. I don't really know the origins because I had took the chillies off a plant in my parent's yard. I just put the seeds in a few pots for fun and they grew and are now bearing fruit. In fact I think I have 3 different cultivars (I have another separate question for another type). I think the original one was smaller than these, but I blame that to lack of fertiliser and sparser watering at my parents. I have picked the first one since I took the photo, and it is quite hot... Although I am not too tolerant to very hot chillies so can't say on what scale it is.

Comment: You are welcome! It could also be Cayenne, that is a fairly common one for people to grow in the US (if that is where you are).

Comment: No actually I live on an island in the Mediterranean (Malta), although I don't think we have any particular species or cultivars that are specific to here. I guess it could be Cayenne from pictures I found on Google... although I had the impression Cayenne typically had a longer / narrower kind of fruit.